# How to align spinner view inside RelativeLayout in Android?

Tags: android-layout, android

Im trying to center a spinner inside of a relative layout.
my attempt is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/typesSpinner"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This works well for me in other cases, but not with spinner.
Why?

Comment: You mention trying to center it in a RelativeLayout, but your example is using a LinearLayout.

Comment: I actually meant to use linear layout, as Im kind of used to it. I didnt know that its that easy with relative layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you actually want a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as your wrapper. The following should work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could  also just use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yeah, one line is definitely better than 2, I'll update my answer

Comment: I actually meant to use Linear, but since its working quite easy with Relative, I dont mind. thanks